# Looping through all form elements

Tags: javascript, validation

I need to loop through all the form elements and get the text out of them and pull out any unwanted values. Values such as `` ':,.{}\|*&^%$#@!~`?/ `` and so forth to ensure that I don't have any injection attacks on my website. I am a javascript noob and I need some help with doing this.

Any advice?

Comment: Are you opposed to using a library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said jQuery is okay to use:

```
$(":input").each(function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, ''));
});
```

While client side validation can be beneficial to the user experience, server side validation should not be skipped.

Comment: How is the 1st part do anything as an answer?

Comment: @Neal - A code sample that removes the characters the OP specifically asked about doesn't do anything as an answer?

Comment: lol you changed your answer. look at the timestamp of my comment vs the timestamp of your update....

Comment: @Neal - The only code added was the regular expression which the OP could have easily thrown in himself.  I got back and decided to throw it in for him.  In comparison to no code samples provided....

Comment: Why not `$(":input").val(function(i, v){ return v.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '') });`?

Comment: I don't understand how this works?  what is input?  Is it looping through each form element?  That part in the replace section, is that a string?
Is this on $(document).ready function?

Comment: Is that even a string in the first part of the function?  Why no ' ' apostrophies?

Comment: @Joseph Silber - Yes, there are frequently multiple ways to write code.  That method will work as well.  Without looking at the source of jQuery I'm not sure which one will perform better.

Comment: @DmainEvent - The part in the replace section is a regular expression.  You can call the code at any point in your process where you want the replace to occur (e.g. when the user clicks a submit button).

Comment: So that regex is only catching what?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working?  I am still passing those characters to the server... 
Here is what I have so far 
$(":input").val(function(i, v){ return v.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '') }); except I use this as my regex...
/\/,\.\{\}\[\]\\-\+\=~\!@#\$%\^&\*\:;_\|/

Comment: Anything that does *not* match this whitelist is replaced: a-z, A-Z, 0-9, including the _ (underscore) character and whitespace characters (tab, newline, space, etc)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3044/discussion-between-ek0nomik-and-dmainevent)

Answer (score 4):

If you must do this, here is a base (vanilla javascript, no libs) to work from:

```
var els = document.forms[0].elements;
for (var el in els) {
  var val = el.value;
  if  (/[':,.{}\|*&^%$#@!~`?/]/.test(val)) {
    // Potential issue, do your repairs here
    el.value = fixedValue;
  }
}
```

**EDIT**: Escaping be damned, I'm sure I should have escaped something in there but I don't much care. :)

Comment: +1. But if you do this, be sure to do server-side validation as well. As has been mentioned, client-side validation is easy to bypass.

Comment: +1. Although there's no need to escape the pipe (or anything else in there, for that matter).

Comment: That looks pretty good.  Thanks.  I do server side validation as well.  It's just I am so lousy at JavaScript...

Comment: @Joseph Silber: Actually, I'm not escaping the pipe - well, not intentionally - it was one of the characters the DmainEvent wanted checked (I copied and pasted his little block).

Comment: Then you'll have to escape the slash :P

Answer (score 2):

Do validation on the server side.

It will be much safer there :-)

---

By safer I mean that a user cannot play around with the validation code to make it so his or her inputs go through when they shouldn't.

Or if the user *turns off* javascript, and you have **no** server side validation, then your input is not validated **at all**.

Comment: "much" safer? meaning, doing it in Javascript is safe "to some degree"? ;)

Comment: Safer mean that javascript validation is just a nicety, it will only stop the least determined type of attacker.  Theres an easy way to defeat javascript validation, turn off javascript. Or use modern browsers on the fly editing capability to disengage it.

Comment: I agree that server-side validation is a must. But that doesn't mean that you can't add client-side validation too. Some of the best webapps have as-you-type validation that tells you what you're doing wrong before you even submit the form. Instant feedback is nice.